# Mongoose error "E11000 duplicate key error collection" while inserting multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to import some data into MongoDB and keep running into this error.

`MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: MyDB.clist_list index: clients.email_1 dup key: { clients.email: null }`

Model:

```
interface Client {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

interface Agent {
  pipedrive_id: number;
  name: string;
  clients?: Array<Client>;
}

const clientSchema = new Schema<Client>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator(str: string) {
        return /^\w+([\\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(str);
      },
      message: 'Please enter a valid email',
    },
    required: [true, 'Email required'],
  },  
});

const agentSchema = new Schema<Agent>({
  pipedrive_id: { type: Number, required: true },
  name: String,
  clients: [clientSchema],
});

const AgentClients = model<Agent>('client_list', agentSchema);
```

As you can see on the Model, the clients collection is optional.
Also each run the DB is removed (deleted) and created completely now (just for testing purposes, so that there are no left over indexes or whatnot).

And here's the payload.

```
[
  {
    first_name: 'Jen Test',
    pipedrive_id: 2186,
    clients: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Carl Test',
    pipedrive_id: 2191,
    clients: []
  }
]
```

This is the part that confuses me. How can `email` have a duplicate value of `null` when there are no `Clients` ???

I'm using the `insertMany` method on the Model to insert the data (if that is of any help).

I know there are tons of similar Questions here on this subject but none have my specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `unique: true` on the `email` property in the **clientSchema**. And since both of your inputs does not have `email` specified, MongoDB will assume it's `null`.

So you have a conflict there. On one side you specified that `email` has to be unique, and on the other side you are trying to insert 2 documents with the same `email` value of `null`.

If you want to keep the `email` field unique, and in the same time to allow `null` values, you should check for [Sparse Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-sparse/).

In your schema, you should pass additional property `sparse: true`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But how do I bypass this? Because there will be cases (like the current payload) where the email value is null for both Documents, and since when inserting many the index for the email field will be null and hence throw an error when the second doc also has the same index.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?